# Flutter Ripple Effect Disable But Keep Color Change

Tags: android, flutter, widget

I would like to have the result of the ripple(e.g the color has been overlayed in a greyish color) to be instant(without the animation).
I tried disabling it but it do not change color, can I keep the color change while disabling the ripple animations?
Thanks very much.

Comment: can you please  provide the code ,so we can get more information

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.